# Paypal 580022 error: Chained instant payment flow "The primary receiver is based in a country that isn't enabled to send payments using balance"

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

With regards to the sandbox environment, when I try using India as the locale/country for primary receiver, I get the following message in my error logs:

```
(
                [errorId] => 580022
                [domain] => PLATFORM
                [subdomain] => Application
                [severity] => Error
                [category] => Application
                [message] => The primary receiver is based in a country that isn't enabled to send payments using balance
            )
```

But when I set the primary receiver test account to a US country, it works like a charm, right from completion of payment to the refund process. Virtually, no problems at all.

Can I apply for LiveApp, given to the fact that in the test environment, I, the primary receiver, belong to a country other than what I actually am? Will this affect the approval process?

Comment: The message is pretty clear: the service isn't available in that country (because Indian regulators have been quite hostile to PayPal). If you are in that country and try to work around the regulations by pretending to be in some other country... well... probably not the smartest.

Comment: I do agree but my audience or customer outreach is completely non-Indian for this reason alone. While this is the intent, on a simulateed transaction, the sender and secondary receiver are non-Indians!